# Changing date format when fetching data from MySQL in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, date

Currently I fetch data from a MySQL database to a html table. The data is inserted via an html form first.

One of the fields contains a date, which is entered in format `dd.mm.yyyy`.

I already changed the date format in phpMyAdmin using the browser transformation feature. That works just fine.

Unfortunately, the dates in my html table is still in default date format `mm-dd-yyyy`.

My query currently looks like this: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY ID DESC";`

My table has 6 columns, which should all be displayed in my html table. How do I have to change my query in order to get my desired date format in the html table?

Hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.

This is how my query and while loop looks like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY ID DESC";
$query = mysqli_query($verbindung,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Number</th>';
    echo '<th>Date</th>';
    echo '<th>Time</th>';
    echo '<th>Description</th>';
    echo '<th>Place</th>';
    echo '<th>Taken</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
        while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>' . $fetch['ID'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $fetch['Date'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $fetch['Time'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $fetch['Description'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $fetch['Place'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $fetch['Taken'] . '</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
        }
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below query.

```
$sql = "SELECT ID,DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d/%m/%Y'),Time,Description,Place,Taken FROM tablename ORDER BY ID DESC";
```

For more formats refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately I fetch all the data in my query. Or do I just have to list all columns I want to fetch inside the query?

Comment: Always recommended to mention column names in the query. Why to fetch unnecessary data!

Comment: That is how my query and the while loop looks like. 
I just deleted some html markup.

Comment: Can u update this in ur question? Also please format it before updating it. Its unreadable as of now.

Comment: Cant find date in your code. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Updated it in my question. Date is the third column i fetch.

Comment: What do I have to change inside the while loop? `$fetch['Date']` to -> `$fetch['DATE_FORMAT']` ? Because that does not work, as of index is not defined.

Comment: You dont have to change anything. What is the exact error?

Comment: The error message says `Notice: Undefined index: Date in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 194`

Comment: What is the database column name for the date field?

Comment: It is called `Date`.

Comment: its just a notice anyways, you can disable it. Put this at top of your php code `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: Update me if it gets sorted. If not will assist you tomorrow. I need to go to bed, its too late here.

Comment: Actually that turns off the error report. However, the date is not displayed at all.

Comment: Had a look at that again. 
Was a simple bug I missed. 
I changed the query from `DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d/%m/%Y')` to `DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS ChangedDate` and changed that value in my while loop, too.

Thank you for your help, appreciate it a lot.